# Python - Kivy - on_enter - Cannot address widget in Screen

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to hide progress bar as soon as screen shows in below code. However it gives " AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'" error.

I tried to debug the code and what I saw was that when self is invoked inside on_event, it cannot address itself to "win_Main" screen therefore ids of self does not work.

What is the proper way to adress progress bar just before form opens ?
Thanks in advance...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

f_path = ""
wbk = ""

dsg_main_height = 460   # dsg: Design Related Variables
dsg_image_ratio = 0.12


class MyWinMan(ScreenManager):
    pass


class W_MainMenu(Screen):

    def on_enter(self):
        self.hide_widget(self.ids.pgb_sql_read, True)

    def hide_widget(self, wid, dohide=True):
        
        if hasattr(wid, 'saved_attrs'):
            if not dohide:
                wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled = wid.saved_attrs
                del wid.saved_attrs
        elif dohide:
            wid.saved_attrs = wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled
            wid.height, wid.size_hint_y, wid.opacity, wid.disabled = 0, None, 0, True

    def transform_to_filechooser(self):
        pass
        
    def import_to_sql(self):
       pass

class W_FileSelector(Screen):
    pass


Builder.load_string("""


MyWinMan:

    W_MainMenu:
    W_FileSelector:

<W_MainMenu>:
    
    name:           "win_Main"

    BoxLayout:

        orientation:    "vertical"
        size:           root.width, root.height
        padding:        40
        spacing:        10

        Button:
            text:       'Browse for Source Excel File'
            font_size:  20
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "win_FS"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.transform_to_filechooser()

        ProgressBar:
            id:         pgb_sql_read
            min:        0
            max:        100
            value:      0
            size_hint:  ( 1, 0.1)

            
<W_FileSelector>:
    
    name:   "win_FS"
    id:     my_widget

    BoxLayout:

        orientation: 
            "vertical"
        size:       root.width, root.height
        padding:    50
        spacing:    20

        Label:
            text:       'Please select the file...'
            size_hint:  ( 1, 0.1)
            font_size:  20

""")


Window.size = (700, dsg_main_height)
Window.top = 50
Window.left = 100

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return W_MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I also tried to replace; `self.hide_widget(self.ids.pgb_sql_read, True)` with `Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.hide_widget(self.ids.pgb_sql_read, True))` but this also did not work athough it did not block the app opening. I didn't get why this solution did not work tough.

Comment: Your `kvlang` already contains a `root` widget. Why don't you return it from method `build` instead of creating another `root`.

Comment: changed builder start string to `kv = Builder.load_string("""` and class return to `return kv`.  However this did not solve my issue.

Comment: No, that will not solve the problem. However it's unusual to define `root` widget in `kvlang` but not using it.

Comment: I'm new to kivy even to python :) I was experimenting things and left it like that as it is also working in this way. But after what you said I understand that I'm changing root widget by doing so. Thanks for the info. Do you have any idea about the problem itself ?

Comment: By the way I changed my approach at my main code. I now removed this widget from design and added it later with add_widget. But I will not remove this question as I also wonder how it may be achieved (if it can) with this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `id`s in the `kvlang` is not created yet while you declare the `root`. One way to solve this would be just to set a conditional statement in method `on_enter` over `id`s or over the `ProgressBar` widget (by creating a reference to it).

You can do it like :

1. If you don't want to create a reference for the `ProgressBar` (or you don't need to), the following will also work (but perhaps not an elegant approach).

```py
class W_MainMenu(Screen):

    def on_enter(self):
        # First check whether or not the ids are created, if yes perform the action.
        if self.ids:
            self.hide_widget(self.ids.pgb_sql_read, True)
```

2. Or by creating a reference for `ProgressBar`.

```py
class W_MainMenu(Screen):
    prog_bar = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_enter(self):
        # First check whether or not the ProgressBar is loaded, if yes perform the action.

        if self.prog_bar:
            self.hide_widget(self.ids.pgb_sql_read, True)
```

Now refer the `ProgressBar` in `kvlang` as,

```py
<W_MainMenu>:
    prog_bar: pgb_sql_read
    
    name:           "win_Main"

    BoxLayout:
```

As a side note (and as mentioned in comments) you can declare the already created `root` (in `kvlang`) from method `build` as,

```py
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
```

where 'kv' is the string,

```py
kv = ("""

MyWinMan:

    W_MainMenu:
    W_FileSelector:

<W_MainMenu>:
    prog_bar: pgb_sql_read
    
.
.
.

""")
```

---

### Update:

The above answer tried to address what you mentioned in your question namely, ***'Python - Kivy - on_enter - Cannot address widget in Screen***'.

If you want to make `ProgressBar` disappear as app started (but perhaps make it reappear later), you can implement that within `kvlang` by using certain flag to set some condition(s).

First in your class `W_MainMenu`,

```py
class W_MainMenu(Screen):
    hide_progress = BooleanProperty(True)
```

Then in its design within `kvlang`,

```py
        ProgressBar:
            id: pgb_sql_read
            min: 0
            max: 100
            value: 0
            size_hint: (1, None) if root.hide_progress else (1, 0.1)
            height: 0 if root.hide_progress else self.height
            disabled: root.hide_progress
            opacity: int(not root.hide_progress)
```

Now, perhaps you want to make it reappear again (in this case I added an extra `Button` in your screen `W_FileSelector` in order to trigger that event).

```py
...
        Label:
            text: 'Please select the file...'
            size_hint:  ( 1, 0.1)
            font_size:  20

        Button:
            text: "Go to main page"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "win_Main"
                app.root.current_screen.hide_progress = False
...
```

Comment: I tried your solution. It adresses ids in this approach but somehow still does not hide the progress bar. In fact it should have worked. I could not understand where the problem is. Did you try the code and see if progress bar is hiding or not ?

Comment: I debug both the solutions. The logic does not seem to work as if clause never return true at first run. But thanks for your time anyway. Can you check it again ?

Comment: Can't follow what do you mean by *'still does not hide the progress bar...'* ? Isn't it already there in your code ?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is hide the progress bar widget in UI as soon as program starts. But now it is still visible in UI when you run the code and window pops up.

Comment: Well, the above answer tried to address what you mentioned in your question namely, ***Python - Kivy - on_enter - Cannot address widget in Screen***. In case you want to make the widget disappear on some condition(s) you may implement that within `kvlang` by using certain flag.

Comment: Well you are right. I named the question wrong. My intention was what I wrote above. Also I wrote at the definition that **"I am trying to hide progress bar as soon as screen shows in below code."**. Also using kvlang and certain flags are already adressed as hide function works flawlessly unless it is inside on_open. You can try it by yourself. And for the last point your code still do not seem to address progress bar widget as true parts of the if clause does not seem to trigger in any of the solutions. Please correct me if I am wrong. Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: With the updated approach you don't need to call anything within the method `on_enter`. Whatever are needed to make the widget's appearance switchable, have already been implemented using `kvlang` with the help of the flag var.

Comment: Not the exact same thing but you are right. I will not extend the issue more as I already solved this issue with another appoach as I stated above. Once again thanks for assistance...